# how to do i convert an value into an array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am enabled to validate a function if it is an array of two or more value

```
const validateZIPLength = (zip) => (
  zip.length > 5 || zip.length < 5 ?
    'zip code should be 5 digits': undefined
)
validateZIPLength('123')
for the above function cal, it works fine

validateZIPLength(['1234', '12345'])
```

it should return the zip code should be 5 and undefined but it is returning only zip code should be 5 for the 1st item in the array

Comment: `['1234', '12345'].map(validateZIPLength)`

Comment: the problem is that if it is single address this approach works fine validateZIPLength('123') but how to write a check condition in the function itself if there is an array of zip's

Comment: If you can't control how the zip is going to be passed to the function validateZIPLength then you could put a check inside the function to see if what is passed is an array. It would look something like this:
`cont validateZIPLength = (zip) => (
if (Array.isArray(arguments[0])) {
  arguments[0].map((z) => { zip.length > 5 || zip.length < 5 ? 'zip code 
  should be 5 digits': undefined
 })
} else {
  Code for if just the zip
}
`

Answer (score 1):

Your function can only handle individual values, not arrays.

Here's how you can add support for arrays :

```js
function validateZIPLength(zip) {
  if(Array.isArray(zip)) {
    for(let i = 0; i < zip.length; i++) {
      zip[i] = validateZIPLength(zip[i]);
    }
    return zip;
  } else {
    return zip.length === 5 ? undefined : "zip code should be 5 digits";
  }
}

console.log(validateZIPLength(['1234', '12345']));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help the function seems to work fine and I was expecting this functionality

Comment: when I'm trying to use this function a lint error is thrown stating Unexpected negated condition

Comment: thanks for the help but the still same issue at this line Unexpected negated condition else {
    return zip.length !== 5 ? "zip code should be 5 digits" : undefined;

Comment: @viky : I made another change to the code. Could you try again? I'm pretty sure it works now. — And if you're still having an issue, could you tell me what linter you're using?

Comment: Hi john when i'm using the above function it is returning undefined is there any means that if there are no errors can i return an empty array instead of undefined in an array

Comment: @viky : You can return anything you want. Please let me know what exactly you want in which circumstances, and I'll modify my function accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

> `validateZIPLength(['1234', '12345'])`
>
> it should return the zip code should be 5 and undefined but it is
>   returning only zip code should be 5 for the 1st item in the array

Actually, what happens is that the function `validateZIPLength` returns what you get for the *entire array* itself, not for the first element. When you pass in the array, it doesn't know if it got a string or an array, it simply checks the length as per `zip.length > 5 || zip.length < 5` and since an array *also* has a [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property, the code works as you instructed it - it gets `2` because there are two elements in the array and thus returns you the string `'zip code should be 5 digits'`.

Remember, computers are stupid - they do what you *tell* them to, not necessarily what you *want* them to.

Since you have a function that takes strings and gives you results, but you want to apply it against many elements of an array, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which does exactly that for you. It takes a function and calls it with each member of the array. You then get a new array that contains each result.

```js
const validateZIPLength = (zip) => (
  zip.length > 5 || zip.length < 5 ?
    'zip code should be 5 digits': undefined
)
const singleInvalidZIPCode = validateZIPLength('123');
const singleValidZIPCode = validateZIPLength('12345');

console.log("single invalid ZIP code:", singleInvalidZIPCode);
console.log("single valid ZIP code:", singleValidZIPCode);

const multipleZIPCodes = ['1234', '12345'].map(validateZIPLength)

console.log("multiple ZIP codes:", multipleZIPCodes);
```